# How to modify android string.xml or our own xml file runtime

Tags: android, xml

My requirement is I need to modify client configuration information into one values/client_configuration.xml at runtime. I Google it, couldn't resolve issue. I don't want to keep in `sharedPreference`. Because this application already developed need to do some modification only. So are there any ways to change file?

please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: String.xml are string constants you will not be able to change the content. - I would use SQLite

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change any files that are included with the application as it's distributed.  What you can do is copy an XML file from inside you `assets` folder, for example, to the internal storage and then use it from there.  You can modify the file on local storage as necessary.  Or use a sqlite database.

You didn't provide any context about what it is you really need to do, but it sounds like you don't have a full understanding of how apps utilise storage.  I strongly suggest you read [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) sections of the Android documentation.